# android AutoCompleteTextview Designed by html format without a custom class

Tags: java, android, html, tostring, autocompletetextview

I  design my textView by html format  in string.xml and it's work to me,
when I try to apply this on autoComplete via ArrayAdapter  it's don't work :(
Someone has a solution??

//Student Class toString() override

```
@Override
public String toString() {

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.welcome_messages),
            string1, string2);
    CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
    return styledText.toString();
}
```

//init adapter to AutoCompleteTextView in Activity

```
public void second(ArrayList<Student> list) {
    Student.context = this;
    ArrayAdapter<Student> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Student>(this,
            R.layout.my_textview, list);
    AutoCompleteTextView completeTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.students);
    completeTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

// string.xml

```
<string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have &lt;b>%2$s new messages&lt;/b>.</string>
```

Comment: "when I try to apply this on autoComplete via ArrayAdapter it's don't work" - how, exactly? Crash? Stack trace? In which class are you overriding the `toString` method?

Comment: The text appears normal like in the default, with no design

Comment: I override in Student class

Comment: requires convert to string-"Type mismatch: cannot convert from CharSequence to String"

Comment: when I convert it's not work at all